# Que debo de hacer evitar que se pierdan los datos antes de cargar el diseñador? (Error visual studio)

Tags: visual-studio-2015

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]este es el error que me presenta el  visual studio ¿Alguien me podria ayudar?

Comment: Hola Thomas. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. ¿Qué error?  Puedes explicar más tu situacion y lo que intentas? **Mira [ask] para mejorar la pregunta**. Un saludo

Comment: Por favor, por el mensaje de errro en formato de texto, no de imagen, y muestra tu codigo para contextualizar el error. (Parece que has modificad a mano un `.Designer`, archivos autogenerados que no deberias modificar tú) Un saludo

Comment: A mi me aparece ese error cuando elimino alguna referencia en el .cs de un control puesto en el designer. Eliminaste alguna parte de tu código??

Comment: Explícanos que hicistes para llegar a este punto, también muéstranos (en texto, no con una imágen) el contenido de `Form1.Designer.cs` y `Form1.cs`.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que entiendo en el mensaje, uno de tus botones en el formulario, mas especificamente, button2, tiene asociado el evento click a un método en tu código, y le modificaste el nombre al método de forma manual.

Ve a tu código y vuelve a ponerle el mismo nombre al método que renombraste, o crea un método que se llame así para que no te muestre el error el diseñador:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Como recomendación, si quieres cambiarle el nombre a un método creado por el diseñador, lo mejor es usar la refactorización, es fácil, cuando renombres el método, este va a quedar como remarcado con puntitos alrededor, en ese momento, presiona el foquito que sale y selecciona cambiar nombre, de esta forma el mismo visual studio va a renombrar el método en todas las otras partes donde se hacía referencia, incluyendo en el código que generó el diseñador, y así no te dará error.